# Need to post JSON data to an endpoint with an ugly JSON structure

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to post JSON data to an endpoint that requires the data to be formatted exactly to specification. The JSON format is ugly and fails if data is posted any other way then described.

I have all the required data in a separate IEnumerableObject that I need to prepare in the JSON format described below

I've tried various way to format the data to fit this list but I think there must an easier way..

jsonConverter to c# class tool has provided me with the following nested class structure.

```
internal class ActivityModel
{
    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Properties Properties { get; set; }
}

internal class Properties
{
    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$values")]
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
}

internal class  Value
{
    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    public string Type { get; set;  }

    public JObject Name { get; set; }

    public JObject ValueValue { get; set; }
}
```

JSON FORMAT, must be posted exactly as so. :

```
{
    "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericEntityData, Asi.Contracts", --- THIS IS HARDCODED
    "Properties": {
        "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyDataCollection, Asi.Contracts", --- THIS IS HARDCODED
        "$values": [
            {
                "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts", --- THIS IS HARDCODED
                "Name": "ACTIVITY_TYPE", --- THIS IS HARDCODED
                "Value": "Education" --- THIS IS HARDCODED
            },
            {
                "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
                "Name": "PartyId",
                "Value": myVariable
            },
             {
                "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
                "Name": "muf_1",
                "Value": myVariable
            },

             {
                "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
                "Name": "muf_5",
                "Value": myVariable
            },

             {
                "$type": "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
                "Name": "muf_6",
                "Value": myVariable
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

What I've tried to do so far:

```
var partyID = builtResponse.First().PartyId;
string muf_1 = builtResponse.First().MUF_1;
string description = builtResponse.First().Description;
string courseCode = builtResponse.First().Product_Code;
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
ActivityModel activityModel = new ActivityModel();

activityModel = new ActivityModel()
{
    Type = "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericEntityData, Asi.Contracts",
    Properties =
    {
        Type = "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyDataCollection, Asi.Contracts",
        Values =
        {
            new Value()
            {
                Type = "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
                Name = "Activity_Type", ValueValue = "Education"
            },
            new Value()
            {
                Type = "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
                Name = "PartyId", ValueValue = partyID
            },
            new Value()
            {
                Type = "Asi.Soa.Core.DataContracts.GenericPropertyData, Asi.Contracts",
                Name = "Description", ValueValue = description
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The code is building fine and no buildtime errors, but now I am getting an object not set to a reference error. Not very helpful..

Comment: Where is the code you have tried, along with its problematic output?

Comment: If you have the Asi.Contracts assembly it would work out of the box with NewtonSoft JSON (without you needing to define a type property) as the $type fields are a special marker by NewtonSoft JSON to know why the target types are.

Comment: I want to call this outside the server. over REST

Comment: @glenebob, I've added my piece of code but the error does not make sense to me. Any insight on what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Please add the full text of the exception you are getting. I don't believe the code that throws the exception is present; please add it. Please add the code that is actually trying to generate the JSON. We need https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Turns out it was just a capitalization issue on the JSON property. Problem fixed, thanks for your help all

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public class Value
{
    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("$values")]
    public List<Value> Values { get; set; }
}

public class ActivityModel
{
    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Properties Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting an Object not set to reference error